# Making one checkbox act like a radio buttom

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, checkbox

So I have this pizza order form, and for the topping section, I want multiple selections to be able to be checked. For example, a user can check pepperoni, sausage, olives, etc. But if the user selects "No Toppings", I want it to clear the rest of the checkboxes. I tried writing some JavaScript to do it, but it was unstable and it only worked onClick. So basically, I don't want users to be able to select "No Toppings", I want nothing else to be selected, and when users select a different topping, I don't want "No Toppings" to be selected. I hope this makes sense! Any help is appreciated! Here is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function unCheck(el, n){
    el.form.elements[n].checked = false;
  }
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: none;">
      <input name="size" type="radio" value="8.00" id="small" 
             onclick="this.form.total.value=calculateTotal(this);" />
      <label for="small">Small ($8.00)</label>
    </td>
    <td style="border: none;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="pepperoni" value="0.50" 
             onclick="this.form.total.value=calculateTotal(this);"/>
      <label for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label>

      <input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="sausage" value="0.50" 
             onclick="this.form.total.value=calculateTotal(this);" />
      <label for="sausage">Sausage</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: none;">
      <input name="size" type="radio" value="10.00" id="medium" 
             onclick="this.form.total.value=calculateTotal(this);" />
      <label for="medium">Medium ($10.00)</label>
    </td>
    <td style="border: none;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="mushroom" value="0.50" 
             onclick="this.form.total.value=calculateTotal(this);" />
      <label for="mushroom">Mushroom</label>

      <input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="olive" value="0.50"
             onclick="this.form.total.value=calculateTotal(this);" />
      <label for="olive">Olive</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: none;">
      <input name="size" type="radio" value="12.00" id="large" 
        onclick="this.form.total.value=calculateTotal(this);"/>
      <label for="large">Large ($12.00)</label>
    </td>
    <td style="border: none;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Un_CheckAll" value="0.00" id="none" 
             onclick="unCheck(this, 'pepperoni','sausage', 'mushroom', 'olive'); "/>
      <label for="none">No Toppings (Cheese Pizza)</label> 
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a javascript library like jQuery? It would make this much easier to solve.

Comment: Yes, I agree, although it's an assignment and I have to follow some guidelines and we can only use javascript.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not to familiar with the site.

Comment: I agree with the guys mentioning `jQuery`.  Even if your professor doesn't allow it, you should learn it just for your own sake, it makes things much easier.  For the current assignment though, you're going to have to handle everything manually--i.e., hook up a function to uncheck everything to the No Toppings element, and hook a function to uncheck No Toppings to every other element.

Comment: Is this question still active ?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing [jQuery](http://jquery.com), this becomes trivial. [Check out this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/ZzveA/).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use jQuery for this assignment